# CyanogenMod Installer for updating version

Tags: android, cyanogenmod

I've installed CyanogenMod on my Samsung Galaxy S3 about a month ago using the CyanogenMod Installer, it is using Android 4.4.2 now...

[image: version info]

**My question is:** when the CM with 4.4.4 is made available on http://download.cyanogenmod.org what should I do to get this update? in other words:

Should I expect to receive a system notification like a '*system update via OTA*'?

Or

Will I need to use the 'CyanogenMod Installer' and do it all over again, including a letting the device being factory reset?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on [android.se]

Comment: Or XDA-Developers, I believe. But I think you'd have to re-flash it, I'm not 100% certain though. The reason why that is my guess is because of how you would also need to re-flash the appropriate version of Google Apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirming...Cyanogenmod OTA updates work, see the screenshot.

[image: OTA update of Cyanogenmod]